# I am doing everything as always to enable CORS,BUT THIS TIME DOES NOT WORK

Tags: asp.net

Before i always used this approach to enable cors in asp.net web api core and it was with success.But this time i am doing the same thing,but it does not work.I dont understand what is happening.Services.add cors is before services.addmvc and i use the cors middleware in Configure method before i use the mvc.Angular is running on localhiost 4200.And the strange things is that two days ago it worked.Please help

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));

            services.AddDbContext<AuthenticationContext>(x =>
            {
                x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection"));
            });

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
          .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthenticationContext>();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            }
           );


            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                });
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            //Jwt Authentication
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JWT_Secret"].ToString());

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x => {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = false;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 204)
                {
                    ctx.Response.ContentLength = 0;
                }
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(builder => builder
                  .AllowAnyOrigin()
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .AllowCredentials());

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "StaticFiles")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")
            });


            app.UseAuthentication();

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();


            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

put following in `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddCors();
```

and insert following in `Configure` method

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
                  .AllowAnyOrigin()
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyHeader());
```

if error persists then with origin as below:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
                      .WithOrigin("http://localhost:4200/")
                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowAnyHeader());
```